# Wordpress - need to query for three different custom values and find one result max for each

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm working on this site for a client and I am trying to modify the current SQL query based on the clients requests. Currently it looks for the first three posts with the custom field 'homepage' value of 'yes' sorted by date descending.

```
query_posts('showposts=3&meta_key=homepage&meta_value=yes&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16&orderby=date&order=DESC');
```

What is requested now is, there is three post excerpt containers that need to be filled each with one post. Container one with post with value one, container two, value two and container three value three.

So I need to search by three different custom fields and find the one result for each field. Can anyone provide any insight? I'd like to still use the query_posts function if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the most brute force method and called a query for each meta value.

```
        <?php query_posts('showposts=1&meta_key=homepage_location&meta_value=1&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>

        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        <?php query_posts('showposts=1&meta_key=homepage_location&meta_value=2&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>

        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        <?php query_posts('showposts=1&meta_key=homepage_location&meta_value=3&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>

        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* based on all the comments

All you do is iterate through the loop using your query_posts with it's arguments and apply different html to each iteration based on a counter. So;

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=3&meta_key=homepage&meta_value=yes&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16‌​&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>

<? $counter = 1; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <div class="container-<?php echo $counter; ?>">

         <?php the_content(); ?>

     </div>

     <?php $counter++; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Generates the following;

```
<div class="container-1"> Content from post 1</div>
<div class="container-2"> Content from post 2</div>
<div class="container-3"> Content from post 3</div>
```

So you can do whatever you like with those via CSS.

Comment: They are most definitely side by side but I am accessing the posts from outside of Wordpress. I am using the loop currently to display the 3 articles. Does that complicate things?

Comment: Have edited answer - I think I'm answering the question you are asking!!

Comment: The styling and layout I've got covered, but thanks for the help on that. 

What I have currently is query_posts('showposts=3&meta_key=homepage&meta_value=yes&cat=-6&cat=-10&cat=-16&orderby=date&order=DESC');

Then I run <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Are you saying to duplicate that three times for each custom field entry and then call wp_reset() after each?

Comment: Right - have totally redone that answer based on these comments.  Hopefully this will help.